# Can't do this induction proof with sqrt(4) repeating

Tags: induction

[image]

Ok so I realize that the last term will be sqrt(6) but I just don't know how to manipulate this expressions to make it provable by induction. I tried rewriting it using exponents but had no luck with that

Comment: What have you tried so far? What would you need to show to prove by induction? Such initial work should be incorporated into your question as context.

Comment: You don't need induction to prove that. Does the question require you to use induction?

Comment: Like I said i tried rewriting the sqrt(4) using exponents. I know that the expression needs to be manipulated somehow so I can substitute k+1. I also tried squaring both sides and am trying to find a patern here but still no luck

Comment: @Robin Yes the question requires induction

Comment: @user120767 Sometimes it is the case that just writing things properly will help immensely. The LHS of the inequality is short for the more correct: $a_0=2$ and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{4+a_n}$. Now proving what is asked by induction with the proper notation, is trivial.

Comment: can I use a0?
It says n belongs to the natural numbers.

Comment: @user120767If in this case $0$ isn't a natural number, you can just start with $a_1$.But it's unlikely that anyone would count what I wrote as incorrect.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{a_{n+1}+4}$ is lower than $3$ even if $a_n=3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence we are dealing with is recursively defined as $a_n=\sqrt{4+a_{n-1}}$. We need to prove that $a_n<3$ for all $n$.

Base case: $\sqrt{4} = 2 < 3$

Inductive step: We assume that for $n=k$ we have $a_k<3$ and then attempt to show that it follows the inequality holds for $n=k+1$ as well: $$a_k<3 \implies a_k+4 < 7 \implies a_k + 4< 9 \implies \sqrt{a_k+4} < 3 \implies a_{k+1} < 3$$

Comment: @RossMillikan: you're right, I ended up typing $n-1$ instead of $n+1$, it was a typo. See the edited answer.

Comment: Ok so which answer is correct?
Also we do not need a step like n=k+1 here?

Comment: The answer I wrote above is what you want. I rephrased it in terms of $k$ and $k+1$ so it looks more familiar to you now I suppose. See the edited answer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot!!!